# Как можно сохранить MutableMap в shareprefetence?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences

С помощью shareprefetence я сохраняю некоторые числа и строки, но как можно сохранить MutableMap, чтобы я мог с ним работать когда приложение запустится заново, может есть способ не через shareprefetence, или что-нибудь другое?

Comment: а в чём проблема? через forEach переберите мапу и положите в shared preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать Gson для того чтоб конвертировать вашу Mапу:

В String, а затем сохранить как строку в SharedPreferense

```
fun mapToJson(map: HashMap<String, String>): String {
    return Gson().toJson(map)
}
```

Получить из SharedPreferense String и конвертировать обратно в HashMap

```
fun mapFromJson(stringMap: String): HashMap<String, String> {
    val type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(stringMap, type)
}
```

Но я бы крайне не рекомендовал хранить сложные объекты в SharedPreference. Лучше для этого использовать базу данных или запись в файл. SharedPreference это немного про другое.